# Cause To, Lead To

Tags: meaning, word-usage, usage

I have a question about the usages of the verb "*lead*".  According to web usages, one sense of the verb "*lead*" is similar to the verb "*cause*".  So that the following two sentences:

> 1. The recession ***caused*** some investors to back off on buying stocks.
> 2. The recession ***led*** some investors to back off on buying stocks.

, mean the same thing.

Does that mean the following:

> 3. Erosion ***caused*** the building to collapse.
> 4. Erosion ***led*** the building to collapse.

are also the same?  I do feel that sentence 4, which uses "*led*", is a little bit off compared to sentence 3, which uses "*cause*".  What do native speakers think?

Comment: Please cite your sources.

Comment: @meatie - How does your dictionary define **to lead** and **to cause**? What dictionary did you consult before asking this question? At Dictionary.com, what is the 3rd definition of the verb **to lead**?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Definition 3 of this [dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lead?s=t) reads:  "*to influence or induce; cause*".  So, the usage in sentence 4 is okay?

Comment: @meatie - Do you have reason to believe that your dictionary provides false definitions?

Answer (score 3):

There is a subtle difference between "caused" and that version of "lead/led". The first is a direct result:

> The driver caused the accident.

The second may not be as direct - it is on the path to the final outcome, but not the only cause:

> Because he didn't check the tyres, it led to the accident when he drove in the rain.

In the second version, he may not have had an accident even though the tyres were bad. But put all the circumstances together, and it led to the accident.

Comment: I am puzzled. What is the relationship or similarity of these two sentences to the usages in the OP's question? Also, what do you mean by _that version of "lead/led"_? Do you know of other versions of the verb **to lead**?

Comment: The OP's sentences and your second example use different meanings of **led**. The OP's sentences use meaning 3 (with object) and you use meaning 21 (without object) in this dictonary: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lead?s=t . If you cite examples with different meanings, then obviously the meanings are different.

Comment: Definition 3 begins with "to influence", which provides the context of the other terms in that definition. The word can be used to mean "caused", but the question asks what is the difference. If "caused" is the intended meaning of the sentence, it is unambiguous. The only reason to use "led to" rather than "caused" is to imply a lesser than direct relationship. It isn't clear what nits the previous comments seek to pick, but this answer is essentially correct. The concept of being one of many causes could also be described as the action that triggered a series of events leading to the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

*X leads Y* when X makes or encourages Y to follow X.

*Follow* here can mean physically follow, as in *I led my friend out the door*, or follow as in "happen after", such as *I was led to believe he wasn't coming to work after seeing pictures of him drunk last night*.

*Lead* in this sense strongly implies *cause*, sometimes to the point where you could substitute *cause* and not change the meaning very much, but technically it does not actually mean *cause*.

Answer (score 0):

A person or animal can be led, but an inanimate object cannot, as it cannot move or walk of its own will. In question #2, the *investors* were led to back off due to the recession.

In question #4, the direct object is a building, an inanimate object that can't be led, so we would use "caused" instead.

Comment: I think that's a different meaning of "lead to".  In this case, it doesn't mean to guide or direct.  It means to influence or induce an outcome, in the sense of cause.